# Django - is MEDIA_URL still relevant with S3BotoStorage?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-settings, django-storage

Perhaps a misconception on my part, I don't understand what is the purpose of `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` when using S3. The files are uploaded to the bucket so the root is never used, and the url of the `ImageField` is stored inside the image object so the `MEDIA_URL` is never used either. Is this correct? If not, please explain it so I can better understand how everything fits together.

My setup has three buckets:

`static` for js, css, templates, set as `STATICFILES_STORAGE`

`media` for user uploaded images, set as `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`

`spider` for images scraped from other websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using django-storages, you can safely remove these two variables from your settings.py file.

Both variables are used for when you are handling media files on the server itself.

Comment: Thanks. What else does it apply to (does that apply to `STATIC_URL` AND `STATIC_ROOT` as well)?

Comment: It has been a while so I may not remember right. I can tell you that I still have STATIC_URL on my project. If I remember (or think about it), the reason is that you need STATIC_URL because it is used by the {% url %} tag. But it does not make that much senses (as django-storages) should be replacing that. But I kind of remember taking it out and something not working. Just don't remember what